# The unit ball in $L^{\infty}$ is not weakly sequentially compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

I would like to show that $\overline{B_1(0)} = \{x \in L^{\infty} : \|x \|_{L^{\infty}} \leq 1\}$ is NOT weakly sequentially compact (so that $L^{\infty}$ is NOT reflexive). Does this follow from the fact that $\overline{B_1(0)}$ is [not strictly convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806453/unit-ball-of-l1-l-infty-and-cx-is-not-strictly-convex)?

One way to prove this would be to explicitly construct a sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $\overline{B_1(o)}$ which has no weakly convergent subsequences, but I have not been able to think of anything.

Comment: Do you mean $\le 1$?

Comment: Yes, thank you for that correction as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On $I=(0,1)$ define $f_n(x):=\cos(n\pi x)$. It is well known that $f_n \rightharpoonup^* 0$ in $L^\infty(0,1) = L^1(0,1)^*$. If $(f_n)$ would be weakly converging then the weak limit has to be zero.

Define $g\in C([-1,1])^*$ by
$g(f)= f(1)$.
Then $g_1(f_n)=(-1)^n$, which does not converge to zero.

Extend $g$ to $L^\infty(I)^*$ by Hahn-Banach theorem. The extension $\tilde g\in  L^\infty(I)^*$ still satisfies $\tilde g(f_n)\not\to0$.

Comment: Does the half-arrow star notation for convergence to zero refer to weak convergence? Why is it true?

Comment: $\rightharpoonup^*$=weak-star. It holds $f_n \rightharpoonup$ (weak) $f$ for all $L^p$, $p<\infty$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150645/why-sinnx-converges-weakly-in-l2-pi-pi

Comment: What about for $p = \infty$?

Comment: This sequence does *not* converge weakly in $L^\infty$.